# filesyncprovider creates folders for documents with same name as document

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I am building a sync app with a customprovider and a filesyncprovider. I based my provider on this example:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/File-Sync-with-Simple-c497bf87

Now I want to extend to a hierarchical folderstructure. So in the EnumerateItems method of the custom syncprovider I return all files and folders just like I did before with only the files in the directory. Now on the filesyncprovider side, this results in a creation of folders with the name of the file and the file being placed in this folder. E.g.
Folder1\textfile.txt\textfile.txt

I have no idea, what I am doing wrong and I find it hard to know the part of the MS filesyncprovider where I could debug to see, what's happening.

My question is, what am I doing wrong and how can I correct it, so that the correct output would be
Folder1\textfile.txt?

Best regards,

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Must return the relative path without the filename
        public string RelativeDirectoryPath
        {
            get
            {
                return _relativeFilePath;
            }
```

Read first - then ask: I returned the path to the file instead of the path to the folder... comment above even warns not to do that...